# C find all possible sides of a triangle from the perimeter

Tags: c

I keep getting a negative number for c, b just prints 23, a is looping like it should. At least the output adds up to 24 when I put that in for the perimeter. I feel like I'm close just some stupid logic error.
My code is below.

Write a program to find all the triangles with integer side lengths and a user
specified perimeter. Your program should find all the triples a,b and c where a + b + c is user specified perimeter value.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main() {
  4     int p, a, b, c;
  5     printf("Enter a perimeter: ");
  6     scanf("%d", &p);
  7 
  8     printf("Triangles with a perimeter: " " %d\n", p);
  9 
 10     for(a = 1; a < p; a++) {
 11         for(b = a;  b < p; b++)
 12             c = p - (a + b);
 13             b = p - (a + c);
 14             a = p - (b + c);
 15 
 16             printf("%d, %d, %d\n",a,b,c);
 17 
 18 }
 19     return 0;
 20 }
```

I think this is more of an interview question than a beginner problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: To get the right answers mathematically you also need to think about the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

Comment: You need to put brackets around your inner loop, right now on the outer loop has them

Comment: Also, integer lengths pretty much guarantees that b and c will be at least 1. So you can shorten your loops a bit.

Comment: You should also consider that `a + b` cannot be shorter than `c`. For example, `p=24`, when `a=1` and `b=1`, it can't be a triangle even though `c=24-(1+1)`. Imagine a triangle with `1`, `1`, and `22` sides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several things wrong in the original code. Some related to what makes a triangle a triangle and some are fundamental logic gone wrong.

`for (a = 1; a < p; a++)` is wrong because one side of a triangle can't be longer than half the perimeter. Even at half the perimeter, that will make 2 lines, not a triangle.

`for (b = 1;  b < (p - a); b++)` is wrong because `a+b` will be smaller than half the perimeter at the start.

`c` is calculated based on the value of `p`, `a` and `b`.

```
c = p - (a + b);
```

What's the point of calculating `b` and `a`?

```
b = p - (a + c);
a = p - (b + c);
```

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) pointed out, the code should only print the unique triangles. This can be easily accomplished by adding a condition `a<=b && b<=c` before the `printf` statement.

Thanks to @JonathanLeffler for taking the time to debug this short code. A bug was found that caused the code to skip some output due to `b` being initialized to a higher value, and the inner for loop condition that terminates the loop prematurely.

Here's a corrected version of the code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int p, a, b, c;
    printf("Enter a perimeter: ");
    scanf("%d", &p);

    printf("Triangles with a perimeter: " " %d\n", p);

    for (a = 1; 2*a < p; a++) {
        for (b = 1; a+b < p; b++)
            if ((p-2*a) > 0 && (p-2*b) > 0 && (2*a+2*b-p) > 0) {
                c = p - (a + b);
                if(a<=b && b<=c)
                    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a ,b, c);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's try it.

```
Enter a perimeter: 6
Triangles with a perimeter:  6
2, 2, 2
```

That's right. A triangle with perimeter `6` only has `1` possible combination. A `1, 1, 4` unit long sides will not be a triangle unless you are willing to bend the side that is `4` units long.

```
Enter a perimeter: 12
Triangles with a perimeter:  12
2, 5, 5
3, 4, 5
4, 4, 4
```

Comment: Great answer! I wasn't thinking of it from the standpoint of geometry and the rules of trig, merely programmatically based on what the asker provided, but this is very good work. Thanks!

Comment: This code is a lot more logical. I think you can tell I'm still a beginner. I'll have to do more practice problems.

Comment: I previously suggested that by adding the condition `if (a <=b && b <= c)` before the `printf()` for results, you can ensure that you only generate each combination of lengths once. I noted, for example, with p = 12, you get: `(2, 5, 5)`, `(3, 4, 5)`, `(4, 4, 4)` as the output.  What I missed though is that with `p = 11`, adding the condition omits `(3, 5, 3)` (because the code does not generate `(3, 3, 5)` for reasons which elude me).  So, the condition isn't good enough — it does eliminate a lot of duplicate entries (good) but does throw some non-duplicate entries away (bad).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks for finding this bug. The elusive `3, 3, 5` is caused by the initial value of `b` being set to `(p-a)/2` which is `4`, in effect skipping `3, 3, 5`. Some other permutations are also skipped because `(p-2*a) > 0 && (p-2*b) > 0 && (2*a+2*b-p) > 0` causes the inner for loop to terminate prematurely. I'll modify and add your suggestion to limit the printout to unique triangles.

Answer (score 2):

### Duplicate information in the output

The currently accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036443/15168) by [alvits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088572/alvits) generates a lot of duplicate outputs where the combination is a permutation of the same combination of sides.  I adapted the code to print all triangles for perimeters from 3 to 29, and also added a suggested condition `if (a <= b && b <= c)` before the printing operation.

#### `tp17.c`

<sup>*Caution: incorrect code.*</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int p, a, b, c;
    // printf("Enter a perimeter: ");
    // scanf("%d", &p);
    for (p = 3; p < 30; p++)
    {
        printf("Triangles with perimeter: %d\n", p);

        for (a = 1; 2 * a < p; a++)
        {
            for (b = (p - a) / 2; (p - 2 * a) > 0 && (p - 2 * b) > 0 && (2 * a + 2 * b - p) > 0; b++)
            {
                c = p - (a + b);
                if (a <= b && b <= c)
                    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The condition `if (a <=b && b <= c)` before the `printf()` for results is intended to ensure that you only generate each combination of lengths once. I noted, for example, with p = 12, you get: `(2, 5, 5)`, `(3, 4, 5)`, `(4, 4, 4)` as the output.  What I missed though is that with `p = 11`, adding the condition omits `(3, 5, 3)` (because the code does not generate `(3, 3, 5)` for reasons which elude me).  So, the condition isn't good enough — it does eliminate a lot of duplicate entries (good) but also throws some non-duplicate entries away (bad).

Consequently, the code should eliminate the condition, which leaves the program generating a lot of redundant outputs, greatly complicating output comparisons.

#### `tp13.c`

I also created a closely related program, starting from the same base:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int p = 3; p < 30; p++)
    {
        printf("Triangles with perimeter: %d\n", p);
        for (int a = 1; a <= p / 2; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 1; b + a < p; b++)
            {
                int c = p - (a + b);
                if (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a)
                    continue;
                if (a <= b && b <= c)
                    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output comparisons

Part of the `diff -u` output from comparing `tp13` and `tp17` output is:

```
 Triangles with perimeter: 11
 1, 5, 5
 2, 4, 5
-3, 3, 5
+2, 5, 4
 3, 4, 4
+3, 5, 3
+4, 3, 4
+4, 4, 3
+4, 5, 2
+5, 3, 3
+5, 4, 2
+5, 5, 1
 Triangles with perimeter: 12
 2, 5, 5
 3, 4, 5
+3, 5, 4
 4, 4, 4
+4, 5, 3
+5, 3, 4
+5, 4, 3
+5, 5, 2
 Triangles with perimeter: 13
```

Looking at the results for a perimeter of 12, it is clear that `tp17` just generates different permutations.  However, looking at the results for a perimeter of 11 shows that `tp17` generates `(3, 5, 3)` and `(5, 3, 3)` but not `(3, 3, 5)` whereas `tp13` generates `(3, 3, 5)` and not the other two permutations.  However, all the other extra lines in the output from `tp17` in the fragment of output shown are permutations of other lines.

### Different output formatting required

The output formats above do not lend themselves to automatic comparison, so I revised the output to print the perimeter followed by three sides listed in non-decreasing order.  I therefore added code to `tp17.c` to sort the sides into non-decreasing order before printing.  There are probably simpler ways to do it for three elements, but this works.

#### `tp47.c`

```
/* SO 4203-5818 - Calculate all triangles with given perimeter */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int int_cmp(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
    int a = *(int *)va;
    int b = *(int *)vb;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int p, a, b, c;
    for (p = 3; p < 30; p++)
    {
        for (a = 1; 2 * a < p; a++)
        {
            for (b = (p - a) / 2; (p - 2 * a) > 0 && (p - 2 * b) > 0 && (2 * a + 2 * b - p) > 0; b++)
            {
                c = p - (a + b);
                {
                int d[] = { a, b, c };
                qsort(d, 3, sizeof(d[0]), int_cmp);
                printf("%d: %d, %d, %d\n", p, d[0], d[1], d[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### `tp43.c`

```
/* SO 4203-5818 - Calculate all triangles with given perimeter */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int p = 3; p < 30; p++)
    {
        for (int a = 1; a <= p / 2; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 1; b + a < p; b++)
            {
                int c = p - (a + b);
                if (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a)
                    continue;
                if (a <= b && b <= c)
                    printf("%d: %d, %d, %d\n", p, a, b, c);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Except for the printing, this is the same as `tp13.c`.)

#### Comparisons

The outputs can now be sorted and compared.  The `-u` option for `tp43` is superfluous but symmetric.

```
$ tp43 | sort -u -k1n -k2n -k3n -k4n > tp43.out
$ tp47 | sort -u -k1n -k2n -k3n -k4n > tp47.out
$ diff tp43.out tp47.out
$
```

So, the unique outputs are the same, but when you count the differences, there are 390 extra lines in the output from `tp47`:

```
$ tp43 | sort -k1n -k2n -k3n -k4n > tp43-all.out
$ tp47 | sort -k1n -k2n -k3n -k4n > tp47-all.out
$ diff tp43-all.out tp47-all.out | diffcount
deleted 0, inserted 390
$ wc -l tp4?.out tp4?-all.out
     206 tp43.out
     206 tp47.out
     206 tp43-all.out
     596 tp47-all.out
    1214 total
$
```

Just for the record, the files `tp43.out`, `tp47.out`, `tp43-all.out` are identical.  Their content is:

```
3: 1, 1, 1
5: 1, 2, 2
6: 2, 2, 2
7: 1, 3, 3
7: 2, 2, 3
8: 2, 3, 3
9: 1, 4, 4
9: 2, 3, 4
9: 3, 3, 3
10: 2, 4, 4
10: 3, 3, 4
11: 1, 5, 5
11: 2, 4, 5
11: 3, 3, 5
11: 3, 4, 4
12: 2, 5, 5
12: 3, 4, 5
12: 4, 4, 4
13: 1, 6, 6
13: 2, 5, 6
13: 3, 4, 6
13: 3, 5, 5
13: 4, 4, 5
14: 2, 6, 6
14: 3, 5, 6
14: 4, 4, 6
14: 4, 5, 5
15: 1, 7, 7
15: 2, 6, 7
15: 3, 5, 7
15: 3, 6, 6
15: 4, 4, 7
15: 4, 5, 6
15: 5, 5, 5
16: 2, 7, 7
16: 3, 6, 7
16: 4, 5, 7
16: 4, 6, 6
16: 5, 5, 6
17: 1, 8, 8
17: 2, 7, 8
17: 3, 6, 8
17: 3, 7, 7
17: 4, 5, 8
17: 4, 6, 7
17: 5, 5, 7
17: 5, 6, 6
18: 2, 8, 8
18: 3, 7, 8
18: 4, 6, 8
18: 4, 7, 7
18: 5, 5, 8
18: 5, 6, 7
18: 6, 6, 6
19: 1, 9, 9
19: 2, 8, 9
19: 3, 7, 9
19: 3, 8, 8
19: 4, 6, 9
19: 4, 7, 8
19: 5, 5, 9
19: 5, 6, 8
19: 5, 7, 7
19: 6, 6, 7
20: 2, 9, 9
20: 3, 8, 9
20: 4, 7, 9
20: 4, 8, 8
20: 5, 6, 9
20: 5, 7, 8
20: 6, 6, 8
20: 6, 7, 7
21: 1, 10, 10
21: 2, 9, 10
21: 3, 8, 10
21: 3, 9, 9
21: 4, 7, 10
21: 4, 8, 9
21: 5, 6, 10
21: 5, 7, 9
21: 5, 8, 8
21: 6, 6, 9
21: 6, 7, 8
21: 7, 7, 7
22: 2, 10, 10
22: 3, 9, 10
22: 4, 8, 10
22: 4, 9, 9
22: 5, 7, 10
22: 5, 8, 9
22: 6, 6, 10
22: 6, 7, 9
22: 6, 8, 8
22: 7, 7, 8
23: 1, 11, 11
23: 2, 10, 11
23: 3, 9, 11
23: 3, 10, 10
23: 4, 8, 11
23: 4, 9, 10
23: 5, 7, 11
23: 5, 8, 10
23: 5, 9, 9
23: 6, 6, 11
23: 6, 7, 10
23: 6, 8, 9
23: 7, 7, 9
23: 7, 8, 8
24: 2, 11, 11
24: 3, 10, 11
24: 4, 9, 11
24: 4, 10, 10
24: 5, 8, 11
24: 5, 9, 10
24: 6, 7, 11
24: 6, 8, 10
24: 6, 9, 9
24: 7, 7, 10
24: 7, 8, 9
24: 8, 8, 8
25: 1, 12, 12
25: 2, 11, 12
25: 3, 10, 12
25: 3, 11, 11
25: 4, 9, 12
25: 4, 10, 11
25: 5, 8, 12
25: 5, 9, 11
25: 5, 10, 10
25: 6, 7, 12
25: 6, 8, 11
25: 6, 9, 10
25: 7, 7, 11
25: 7, 8, 10
25: 7, 9, 9
25: 8, 8, 9
26: 2, 12, 12
26: 3, 11, 12
26: 4, 10, 12
26: 4, 11, 11
26: 5, 9, 12
26: 5, 10, 11
26: 6, 8, 12
26: 6, 9, 11
26: 6, 10, 10
26: 7, 7, 12
26: 7, 8, 11
26: 7, 9, 10
26: 8, 8, 10
26: 8, 9, 9
27: 1, 13, 13
27: 2, 12, 13
27: 3, 11, 13
27: 3, 12, 12
27: 4, 10, 13
27: 4, 11, 12
27: 5, 9, 13
27: 5, 10, 12
27: 5, 11, 11
27: 6, 8, 13
27: 6, 9, 12
27: 6, 10, 11
27: 7, 7, 13
27: 7, 8, 12
27: 7, 9, 11
27: 7, 10, 10
27: 8, 8, 11
27: 8, 9, 10
27: 9, 9, 9
28: 2, 13, 13
28: 3, 12, 13
28: 4, 11, 13
28: 4, 12, 12
28: 5, 10, 13
28: 5, 11, 12
28: 6, 9, 13
28: 6, 10, 12
28: 6, 11, 11
28: 7, 8, 13
28: 7, 9, 12
28: 7, 10, 11
28: 8, 8, 12
28: 8, 9, 11
28: 8, 10, 10
28: 9, 9, 10
29: 1, 14, 14
29: 2, 13, 14
29: 3, 12, 14
29: 3, 13, 13
29: 4, 11, 14
29: 4, 12, 13
29: 5, 10, 14
29: 5, 11, 13
29: 5, 12, 12
29: 6, 9, 14
29: 6, 10, 13
29: 6, 11, 12
29: 7, 8, 14
29: 7, 9, 13
29: 7, 10, 12
29: 7, 11, 11
29: 8, 8, 13
29: 8, 9, 12
29: 8, 10, 11
29: 9, 9, 11
29: 9, 10, 10
```